# Can't bind UISearchBar in Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, xib

I started a TabBar Application in Xcode. Then I added one tab that I called search. Then I created a UITableViewController with the XIB file called SearchController. In MainWindows.xib I linked the third tab to the XIB file "SearchController".

I created IBOutlet for a UISearchBar. In Interface Builder, I added the UISearchBar and when I ran the project everything was OK but when I tried to bind the UISearchBar to my IBOutlet, it raised an exception when I click on the "search" tab:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UITableViewController 0x4e3ee80> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key searchBar.'
*** Call stack at first throw:"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create the `IBOutlet` for the `UISearchBar` as a property?  Something like this in your `.h` file:

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
```

If so, you forgot to synthesize the property in your `.m` file:

```
@synthesize searchBar = _searchBar;
```